# Why can't get the default configuration file after reinstalling samba?

Tags: debian, configuration, samba, reinstall

I uninstall samba this way:
My os is debian11.

```
sudo rm -f /etc/samba/smb.conf    
sudo apt purge samba
sudo apt install samba
```

Now check the default samba's configuration file.

```
sudo ls /etc/samba/smb.conf
ls: cannot access '/etc/samba/smb.conf': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package which “owns” `smb.conf` is `samba-common`; you need to purge that, and re-install `samba` (since it will be removed when removing `samba-common`):

```
sudo apt purge samba-common
sudo apt install samba
```